# Check whether the elements of a row at a certain index are all different in a 2d array in java

Tags: java

I've been trying to return a true value if the row at the index that I want is unique by doing a bunch of for loops but I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: "by doing a bunch of for loops" great, please, provide your question with the `code` and explain what are trying to achieve with it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could think of would be to just make a set out of the array with the items from the row you want and then just check their lengths. Lengths should be equal if there are solely different items in the array.

```
boolean checkDifferent(int[][] arr, int column) {
    Integer[] arr1d = new Integer[arr.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr1d[i] = arr[i][column];
    }
    
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr1d));
    return (set.size() == arr.length);
}
```